# Subset a data frame and then apply a mathematical question to each subset in a for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, subset

I've been struggling to write a for loop for this specific purpose, and i have quite a large data set so I'd like to learn how to do this in a for loop because the alternative is doing it manually.

To spare you the details about my specific data, I'll refer to this reproducible data frame as an example:

```
mydf<-data.frame(Factor = rep(c("level 1", "level 2", "level 3"), 4),
                  numeric = c(1:12))
 mydf
```

```
Factor numeric
1  level 1       1
2  level 2       2
3  level 3       3
4  level 1       4
5  level 2       5
6  level 3       6
7  level 1       7
8  level 2       8
9  level 3       9
10 level 1      10
11 level 2      11
12 level 3      12
```

I have a categorical (as a factor) and a numerical column, and I'd like to be able to perform calculations on the numerical data for individual levels within the factor, or at the very least to ask R what the mean or standard deviation is for each level. For example, what is the standard deviation of the numeric data belonging to "level 1"?

I haven't used for loops to subset/group data before so I don't even know where to start.

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help

I tried searching for an answer on stack overflow but couldn't find what i needed. I pulled together some ideas from a few different issues where people were needing to filter a data frame in a for loop. I tried this but it just printed out the entire data frame 12 times and then gave the standard deviation for the whole numeric column 12 times rather than for each level

```
    sd<-c()
    for (levels in mydf$Factor){
    a<-dplyr::filter(mydf, Factor == Factor)
    sd<-append(sd, sd(a$numeric))
    }
```

```
sd
     [1] 3.605551 3.605551 3.605551 3.605551 3.605551 3.605551 3.605551
     [8] 3.605551 3.605551 3.605551 3.605551 3.605551
```

I also tried this based on another answer I found here on stack overflow:

```
output<-rep(NA,3)
names(output)<-levels(mydf$Factor)
for (i in 1:length(output)){
  sd[i]<- mean(subset(mydf, Factor == levels(mydf$Factor)[i])$numeric)
}
sd
```

but this gave me:

```
sd
 [1] 5.500000 6.500000 7.500000 3.605551 3.605551 3.605551 3.605551
 [8] 3.605551 3.605551 3.605551 3.605551 3.605551
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly what you want, this will do the work.

```
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

mydf1<-mydf %>% group_by(Factor) %>% mutate(sd=sd(numeric),
                                        mean=mean(numeric),
                                        standardised=scale(numeric))
```

You really do not need loops for this, learn dplyr (or data.table) instead, it will make your life much easier.
Also, look into scales function, you can choose to center around 0 or not

Comment: wow that has just blown my mind! thank you for taking the time to comment

Answer (score 2):

Why would you use loop for this?
You can use dplyr (part of tidyverse set of packages)

```
library(tidyverse)

mydf %>% group_by(Factor) %>% summarise(value=sd(numeric)) %>% View()
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer, it was really helpful. I see what you mean about the loop. I'm thinking ill need a loop in order to perform calculations. For example, one thing I'm trying to achieve with my actual data is to standardise the data just following the formula: (data-mean)/sd, but this needs to be done for each level within the categorical variable. So for each level I need to know the mean and sd, but then I need R to iterate through each numeric data point and calculate a standardisation using the corresponding mean and sd, and then to save it as a new column in the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me, based on the answer provided by procerus.

```
mean<- mydf %>% group_by(Factor) %>% summarise(value=mean(numeric)) %>% data.frame()

sd<- mydf %>% group_by(Factor) %>% summarise(value=sd(numeric)) %>% data.frame()


standardised<-c()
for (i in 1:nrow(mydf)){
  if(mydf$Factor[i] == "level 1"){
    standardised<-append(standardised, (mydf$numeric[i]-mean[1,2])/sd[1,2])
  } else{
    
  } 
  if (mydf$Factor[i] == "level 2"){
    standardised<-append(standardised, (mydf$numeric[i]-mean[2,2])/sd[2,2])
  } else{
    
  } 
  if (mydf$Factor[i] == "level 3"){
    standardised<-append(standardised, (mydf$numeric[i]-mean[3,2])/sd[3,2])
  }
}
standardised
```

I'm definitely open to suggestions on more elegant ways to do this.
Thanks :)